# Automatically marking unexplored areas as code in IDA

Tags: ida

I have a binary file that I am disassembling in IDA. Because IDA can't find every single code path, I need to manually go through and find unexplored areas in the binary and convert them to code by basically repeating Ctrl+U and C. This is obviously very time consuming.

Is there a way to automatically find unexplored areas and attempt to convert them to code?

Comment: You could write a script using [IDAPython](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/) to iterate through and do this. If you haven't explored IDAPython yet, I highly recommend you do so, as it is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I chose to convert the binary image into an ELF file and marked the binary code as executable.

When I loaded this ELF file into IDA, the ELF file headers told IDA that it was a code section and IDA began using its own heuristics to automatically disassemble as much as possible as code.

[Here's the short script](https://gist.github.com/4030336) I used to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can automatically find unexplored areas and convert them to code, but you should be careful when doing so, because as I'm sure you are aware, many unexplored areas will not be valid code.

Depending on the binary, it might be useful to first print a list of all the unexplored areas in the .text section.  IDAPython can do this, e.g.:

```
addr = SegByName(".text")
end = SegEnd(addr)
while addr < end and addr != BADADDR:
    if isUnknown(GetFlags(addr)):
        print "0x%08x" % addr
        addr = NextHead(addr, BADADDR)
    else:
        addr = NextAddr(addr)
print "Done."
```

If you have IDAPython installed, you can run this by selecting File > Python command... and pasting the above code.  It will print the results to the output window, and you can click on any of the printed addresses to jump to the corresponding areas in the disassembly.

If you find that there is a large repeated section of similar unexplored addresses that should be defined as code, you can modify the above script to convert those addresses to code.  The function to define an address as code is MakeCode().

For a rough reference of all of the above functions, you can look [here](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/).  The help index is also occasionally useful.  Its reference is for IDC, IDA's original built-in scripting language, but the IDAPython equivalents of all the IDC functions should be virtually identical.